# Syntax Error AS3 using FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I've search for similar but mine has none of the problems started in others- no naming using protected functions or rogue `{}`.
So can you help- what's wrong?

All for Row 19 (`private function display2`)

> col: 2 Error: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.
>
> col: 2 Error: Syntax error: expecting leftparen before leftbrace.
>
> col: 2 Error: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftbrace.
>
> col: 2 Error: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.

```
{



    package 
    {
        import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityImplementation;
        import flash.display.Bitmap;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.text.TextFormat;
        import flash.display.Sprite;



        /**
         * ...
         * @author Michael
         */
        public class Start extends Sprite   {
                [Embed(source="../lib/Start.jpg")]
                private var StartClass:Class

                            private function display2():void
                            {
                addChild(StartClass());
                myTextBox.text = "Jabble. Click to Scroll Down (下にスクロールする]をクリック). Press Enter to  Instructions alternate between English and Japanese (translations). Press H for the help web page or put http://wp.me/P3FUQl-n in your web browser.  Beneath is the Board and to the right is the Box. Click and Drag Tiles to move it and double click it set it on a square space on the Board or Box and click the Box to change its mode. Jabble- 英語と日本語（訳）との間で交互に指示。を押して、ヘルプWebページのHまたはWebブラウザでhttp://wp.me/P3FUQl-nを置く。下には、理事会で、右側のボックスである。クリックして、それを移動するにはタイルをドラッグし、ダブル会またはボックス上の正方形のスペースには、それを設定してクリックし、そのモードを変更するには、ボックスをクリックしてください" ; 

                myTextBox.width = Box.width;  
                myTextBox.height = Box.height; 
                myTextBox.multiline = true; 
                myTextBox.wordWrap = true; 
                myTextBox.background = true; 
                myTextBox.border = true; 

                var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
                format.font = "Verdana"; 
                format.color = 0xFF0000; 
                format.size = 10; 

                myTextBox.defaultTextFormat = format; 
                addChild(myTextBox); 
                myTextBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownScroll); 
                        }       


        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't declare the variable `myTextBox`.

Comment: just a shot , try to put `;` after `private var StartClass:Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a few mistakes there.
First of all you are adding a class without using the `new` before it.
It needs to be `addChild(new StartClass())` instead of `addChild(StartClass())`.

And seconly, you haven't declared the variable `myTextBox`.
Probably something like `var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and those are errors but fixing those  doesn't solve the syntax errors. Would AS3/Flex have a problem with the very long string declaration?

Comment: Just fixed by itself- no effort by me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because before package you opened {

Comment: That's from me badly copying in the file- its not actually in the file so its not the source the errors. (Line 1 is just package)